# Cannot receive embedded ActiveMQ statistics message

Tags: java, junit, activemq-classic

I am trying to get subscription statistics for my topic from embedded ActiveMQ through my JUnit test.  I am able to subscribe to that topic, send a message to that topic and am able to receive that message in my listener/subscriber.

However, when I try to get statistics from that ActiveMQ, the consumer receive times out.  And if I don't add the "receiveTimeout" than the consumer waits indefinitely for the message. Here is my code for the statistics:

```
    ActiveMQConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false");
    connectionFactory.setStatsEnabled(true);

    Connection connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
    connection.setClientID(format("ActiveMqStatistics-%s", System.nanoTime()));
    connection.start();

    Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    Queue replyTo = session.createTemporaryQueue();
    MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(replyTo);

    String queueName = "ActiveMQ.Statistics.Subscription";
    Queue testQueue = session.createQueue(queueName);
    MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(testQueue);
    Message msg = session.createMessage();
    msg.setJMSReplyTo(replyTo);
    producer.send(msg);

    System.out.println("Statistics request sent. Waiting to receive reply...");

    long receiveTimeout = 5000L;
    MapMessage reply = (MapMessage) consumer.receive(receiveTimeout);
    assertNotNull(reply);

    for (Enumeration e = reply.getMapNames();e.hasMoreElements();) {
        String name = e.nextElement().toString();
        System.out.println(name + "=" + reply.getObject(name));
    }

    connection.close();
```

I get assertion failure because the "reply" is null.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have the StatisticBrokerPlugin installed in your broker?

Comment: Tim: No, I am using the virtual embedded activemq, i.e. the broker URL is "vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false".  Based on the documentation (http://activemq.apache.org/statisticsplugin.html), this should be supported.

Answer (score 1):

I order for this to work you need to create a Broker instance that has the Statistics Broker plugin installed, it is not out of the box.

In the XML configuration you can enable it as follows:

```
<broker ...>
  <plugins>
    <statisticsBrokerPlugin/>
  </plugins>
</broker>
```

Or in a unit test you might create an in VM broker using something similar to the following code.

```
protected BrokerService createBroker() throws Exception {
    BrokerService answer = new BrokerService();
    BrokerPlugin[] plugins = new BrokerPlugin[1];
    plugins[0] = new StatisticsBrokerPlugin();
    answer.setPlugins(plugins);
    answer.setDeleteAllMessagesOnStartup(true);
    answer.addConnector("tcp://localhost:0");
    answer.start();
    return answer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I found the solution. I am configuring the activeMQ embeded broker using the XML and I could add the statisticsBrokerPlugin as follows.

```
<!-- lets create an embedded ActiveMQ Broker -->
    <amq:broker useJmx="false" persistent="false" enableStatistics="true" brokerName="xxx-test-broker" brokerId="xxx-test">
        <amq:transportConnectors>
            <amq:transportConnector uri="tcp://localhost:0" />
        </amq:transportConnectors>
        **<amq:plugins>
            <amq:statisticsBrokerPlugin/>
        </amq:plugins>**
    </amq:broker>
```

> So my activeMQ connection URL will be vm://localhost.

I think this will be useful for someone.